# Modular equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

$$
x^{13}\equiv4\pmod{101}\\x\equiv5^{5^{5^{5}}}\pmod{47\cdot27}
$$
Equations are separate. How should I approach these? Both has something to do with Euler's theorem, I believe, but all my attempts to solve them were futile. I have an idea on the second one, however I'm not sure there is no mistakes.
Is it true that if $y=5^{5^{5}}\pmod{\phi(47\cdot27)}$, then $5^{y}\equiv5^{5^{5^{5}}}\pmod{47\cdot27}$?

Comment: Are they simultaneous congruences or two separate problems?

Comment: They are separate

Comment: Why dont you let us know what did u try and what idea you have?

Comment: Mention that you are asking solutions for two different equations.

Comment: My idea is in the last sentence. Since 5^5^5 = φ(47*27)*k + y and 5^φ(47*27)*k is equivalent to 1, 5^y should be equivalent to x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question
$$x^{13} \equiv 4 \pmod {101} \tag{*1}$$
Since $\gcd(4,101) = 1$, any solution $x$ of $(*1)$ must satisfy $x^{\phi(101)} = x^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod{101}$.
If one can find a positive integer $p$ such that $13\times p \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$, we will have

$$x \equiv x^{13\times p} \equiv 4^p \pmod {101}$$
One can obtain such a $p$ systematically using Euclidean algorithm.

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
100 - 7 \times 13 = 9\\
13  - 9 = 4 
& \implies& 4 
&= 13 - (100 - 7\times 13) = 8\times 13 - 100\\
9   - 2\times 4 = 1 
&\implies&  1 &= (100 - 7\times 13) - 2\times ( 8\times 13 - 100)\\
&&&= 3\times 100 - 23\times 13\\
&&&= (3 - 13)\times 100 + (100-23)\times 13\\
&&&= 77\times 13 - 10\times 100\\
\end{array}$$
This implies we can use $77$ as $p$ and

$$x \equiv 4^{77} \pmod {101}\tag{*2}$$

To evaluate the RHS of $(*2)$. A systematic way is look at the binary representation of
$77$
$$77 = 64 + 8 + 4 + 1 = 2^6 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 1$$
Construct a helper sequence $4^{2^k}$ by repeat squaring and build the desired 
result along the way.

Let's use the computation of $4^{77} \pmod {101}$ as an example.
Under modulus arithmetic when every multiplication is modulo $101$, we have
$$\begin{array}{lll}
& 4^2 \equiv 16\\
\leadsto & 4^4 \equiv 16^2 = 256 \equiv 54
&\leadsto 4^{5} = 4^{4+1} \equiv 54\times 4 = 216 \equiv 14 \\
\leadsto & 4^8 \equiv 54^2 = 2916 \equiv 88
&\leadsto 4^{13} = 4^{8+4+1} \equiv 88\times 14 = 1232 \equiv 20
\\
\leadsto & 4^{16} \equiv 88^2 = 7744 \equiv 68\\
\leadsto & 4^{32} \equiv 68^2 = 4624 \equiv 79\\
\leadsto & 4^{64} \equiv 79^2 = 6241 \equiv 80
&\leadsto 4^{77} = 4^{64+8+4+1} \equiv 80\times20 = 1600 \equiv 85
\end{array}$$

So the answer for the first question is $x \equiv 85 \pmod{101}$.

Answer (score 3):

It seems I've found a solution for the second equation.

Let's find $5^{5^{5}}\pmod{\phi(47\cdot27)}$ :
$$
\phi(47\cdot27)=\phi(47)\phi(27)=46\cdot18=2^2\cdot3^3\cdot23=828
$$
Our goal is, therefore, to find the solution of the following system
$$
\cases{x\equiv5^{5^{5}}\pmod{4}\\
       x\equiv5^{5^{5}}\pmod{9}\\
       x\equiv5^{5^{5}}\pmod{23}}
$$ 
Using the same trick with each of the three:
$$
\phi(4)=2\Rightarrow 5^{5^{5}}=5^{3125}=(5^2)^{1562}\cdot5^1\equiv5^1\equiv1\pmod{4}\\
\phi(9)=6\Rightarrow 5^{5^{5}}=5^{3125}=(5^6)^{520}\cdot5^5\equiv5^5\equiv2\pmod{9}\\
\phi(23)=22\Rightarrow 5^{5^{5}}=5^{3125}=(5^{22})^{142}\cdot5^1\equiv5^1\equiv5\pmod{23}
$$
After applying CRT to the obtained system:
$x\equiv5^{5^{5}}\equiv281\pmod{828}$

Nice, know we know that 
$5^{5^{5^{5}}}=(5^{828})^n\cdot5^{281}\equiv5^{281}\pmod{47\cdot27} $

The final strokes:
$$
\cases{5^{281}\equiv(5^{46})^6\cdot5^{5}\equiv5^{5}\equiv23\pmod{47}\\
       5^{281}\equiv(5^{18})^{15}\cdot5^{11}\equiv5^{11}\equiv2\pmod{27}}\\
\\
x\equiv5^{281}\equiv164\pmod{1269}
$$

And that's the answer:
$5^{5^{5^{5}}}\equiv5^{281}\equiv164\pmod{47\cdot27}$